using the patent center, is it possible to know whether an application applied the Fast Track?
I am researching a patent and want to know whether the applicant filed for the Fast Track.

I assume you are looking into an application not a patent, if so, precision in terminology can be importantl,

Once an application is published all documents submitted by the applicant are available to the public. So, yes.
There are also ways besides that program to get a quicker examination based on age or health of an inventor.
A link to the form.

so what is the precise name of the Fast Track document, if one is filed?
